# formulating latex

Tags: tables, texstudio

[image: .] 
when I run this algorithm there is no error, but when I combine this algorithm into my file, an error occurs. please give me a solution.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\newcommand\mcc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{NiceMatrix}
        & M_1   & M_2 & M_3     & M_4   \\
    J_1 & 0     & 0.66  & 2     & 0.33  \\
    J_2 & 1     & 0     & 1.22  & 0.33  \\
    J_3 & 0     & 1     & 2     & 1     \\
    J_4 & 2.33  & 0.33  & 1.67  & 0     \\
\CodeAfter
\tikz{
    \node (f) [draw, inner xsep=1em, fit=(2-2) (5-5)] {};
    \draw[line width=3pt, opacity=0.2]
        (2-2 |- f.north) -- (5-2 |- f.south)
        (3-2 -| f.west)  -- (3-5 -| f.east)
        (5-2 -| f.west)  -- (5-5 -| f.east);
     }
\end{NiceMatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: .]

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem. Without that. all I can guess is that you forgot the `\usepackage{tikz`}.

Comment: I've changed \documentclass[...]{...} to \ document {article}. when I run it by adding a sentence before the algorithm error occurs. when I add the sentence after the algorithm,no error, but the sentence is not visible on the pdf. 
Likewise when I merge into a task file, the same error.

Comment: I'm glad to see, that my code from your previous question now works for you (it would be nice, that you would  accept may answer if you use its solution) . However, we have any information what is different in your document and provided MWE.

Answer (score 4):

It is almost impossible to help you, if you not provide any information about your document (which document class you use, etc), consequently the my answer on your previous question use `standalone` document class and doesn't bother about placement provided image in your document.

Anyway, my code, which you use for your image is independent from used document class. Also there is no problems with overlapping or not visible text above/below of image. Compilation of it doesn't throw any warnings nor errors. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}


\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
\[
\begin{NiceMatrix}
        & M_1   & M_2 & M_3     & M_4   \\
    J_1 & 0     & 0.66  & 2     & 0.33  \\
    J_2 & 1     & 0     & 1.22  & 0.33  \\
    J_3 & 0     & 1     & 2     & 1     \\
    J_4 & 2.33  & 0.33  & 1.67  & 0     \\
\CodeAfter
\tikz{
    \node (f) [draw, 
               inner xsep=1em, inner ysep=1pt, 
               fit=(2-2) (5-5)] {};
    \draw[line width=3pt, opacity=0.2]
        (2-2 |- f.north) -- (5-2 |- f.south)
        (3-2 -| f.west)  -- (3-5 -| f.east)
        (5-2 -| f.west)  -- (5-5 -| f.east);
     }
\end{NiceMatrix}
\]
\lipsum[12]
\[
\NiceMatrixOptions{%
        code-for-first-row = \scriptstyle\color{red},
        code-for-first-col = \scriptstyle\color{blue}}
%
\begin{NiceMatrix}[first-row,first-col]
        & M_1   & M_2 & M_3     & M_4   \\
    J_1 & 0     & 0.66  & 2     & 0.33  \\
    J_2 & 1     & 0     & 1.22  & 0.33  \\
    J_3 & 0     & 1     & 2     & 1     \\
    J_4 & 2.33  & 0.33  & 1.67  & 0     \\
\CodeAfter
\tikz{
    \node (f) [draw,
               inner xsep=0.8em, inner ysep=1pt, outer sep=2pt, % <---
               fit=(1-1) (4-4)] {};
    \draw[line width=3pt, opacity=0.2]
        (1-1 |- f.north) -- (4-1 |- f.south)
        (2-1 -| f.west)  -- (2-4 -| f.east)
        (4-1 -| f.west)  -- (4-4 -| f.east);
     }
\end{NiceMatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

works fine. The second image is only slightly more fancy version of the first one, It show more possibilities how to use `NiceMatrix` environment.

[image]

So, it is unclear, what is your problem. For sure it is not caused with solution showed in MWE in your question. Source of your problem  with which you are faced, is not caused by it.

Comment: thanks sir, i used tamplate from department of Math.

Comment: how to combine the algorithm with tamplate?

Comment: (i) your thankfulness you can also express by up-vote of unswer (by clicking on the up triangle at top left side of answer), (ii) I'm not member f your math department, so I haven't any clue about your "template". So, please in your question  provide a small but complete document based on your "template" which reproduce your problem and also provide link, where we can download  template of your math department (assuming, that is no publick).

Answer (score 1):

For information, with recent versions of `nicematrix`, it's possible to do that construction without transparency and without the Tikz library `fit`.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{NiceArray}{|cccc|}[first-col,first-row,last-col]
\CodeBefore
  \begin{tikzpicture} [line width = 3pt,lightgray]
      \draw (1-|1.5) -- (last-|1.5) ;
      \draw (2.5-|1) -- (2.5-|last) ;
      \draw (4.5-|1) -- (4.5-|last) ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\Body
        & M_1   & M_2   & M_3   & M_4   & \\
    \Hline
    J_1 & 0     & 0.66  & 2     & 0.33  \\
    J_2 & 1     & 0     & 1.22  & 0.33  \\
    J_3 & 0     & 1     & 2     & 1     \\
    J_4 & 2.33  & 0.33  & 1.67  & 0     \\
    \Hline
\end{NiceArray}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]